# How do I combine multiple queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: coffeescript, elasticsearch, hubot

For reference here is the code. I am trying to make a hubot plugin that logs to elasticsearch and then uses hubot commands to search those logs.

https://gist.github.com/4050748

I am trying to retrieve records that match two queries.

```
{ 
  query: { 
        match: {
          user: "SomeUsername" 
        }, 
        range: {
          date: {
            from: (Date.now() - 3600) 
          }
        }
  },
  size: 50 
}
```

I was expecting:

- Up to 50 records
- records that had the given user
- records in the last hour

I got:

- up to 10 records
- records that had the given user
- from any time

How do I get all the records with some username in the last hour? Do I need to use match_all with filters? Is what I am attempting unsupported?

In SQL it would be something like:

```
Select (*) from messages where user_name = ? and time > ?
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use the [bool query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-query.html) to combine different queries together. You can then choose whether each single query must match, should match (optional), or must not match.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 23):

For anyone who stumbles on this question and wonders what it looks like to combine a match and range query in ElasticSearch, this example would look like

```
curl 'localhost:9200/<index>/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query" : {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "user": "SomeUsername"
          }
        },
        {
          "range" : {
            "date": {
              "gt": "now-1h"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Are the queries run in the order they are specified? As in, range query will be applied on users found by the first one?

Comment: @EvaldasRaisutis I would assume so based on the choice of the API to use a list in "match" but I don't know for sure.