# ElasticSearch fulltext search with bool query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am trying to make full-text search in whole document using

```
"query" => [
    "query_string" => [
        "fields" => ["_all"],
        "query" => "fooA AND fooB"
    ]
]
```

It works pretty good. In the same query I need to run bool query

```
"query" => [
    "bool" => [
        "must" => [
            "term" => [
                "name" => "My_name"
            ]
        ],
        "should" => [
            ....
        ]
    ]
]
```

Is it possible to combine these two queries ? is this proper way to make full-text search ?

In result I need all documents that contains "fooA AND fooB" in any field and special field name equals "My_name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my question thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352146/how-do-i-combine-multiple-queries-in-elasticsearch).

```
"query" => [
    "bool" => [
        "must" => [
            [
                "term" => [
                    "name" => "My_name"
                ]
            ],
            [
                "query_string" => [
                    "fields" => ["_all"],
                    "query" => "fooA AND fooB"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

This combination works for me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can club these together as shown below :

```
GET _search
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "name": "MY_NAME"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "fooA AND fooB",
            "fields": [
              "_all"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn`t work. Error : [query_string] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Comment: Please check now.