# Generating Elastic Search query using Elastic Search 8.9.0 elasticsearch-java in elastic 8.8.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am having a condition as below:
I have "SearchCriteria1", "SearchCriteria2" and so on till "SearchCriteria..n". This criteria is dynamic and can go upto 10 search criterias.

For each of the above criteria I can have sub-criterias as  "SearchCriteria11" , "SearchCriteria12", "SearchCriteria13"

So basically as structured below

SearchCriteria1 --> SearchCriteria11, SearchCriteria12, SearchCriteria13

SearchCriteria2 --> SearchCriteria21, SearchCriteria22, SearchCriteria23

I want this to be searched in elastic search as

```
(SearchCriteria1 OR SearchCriteria11 OR SearchCriteria12 OR SearchCriteria13) AND (SearchCriteria2 OR SearchCriteria21 OR SearchCriteria22 OR SearchCriteria23)
```

This query I needed to be searched across 3 fields in the document , for example: "eventsummary", "address" and "eventdescription"

I am using the following maven dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have tried the below code but does not work as inside the loop the query gets overridden.

```
Query esContextQuery = null, edescContextQuery = null;
for (int i = 0; i < searchCriteria.length; i++) {
      String primCriteria = searchCriteria[i];
      MatchQuery.of(m ->           m.field("eventdescription").query(primCriteria).field("eventsummary").query(primCriteria))._toQuery();
        
if (searchContextCriteria != null && searchContextCriteria.length > 0) {
    for (String contextSkill : searchContextCriteria) {
        MatchQuery.of(m -> m.field("eventdescription").query(contextSkill))._toQuery();
     }
}

if (searchContextCriteria != null && searchContextCriteria.length > 0) {
    for (String contextSkill : searchContextCriteria) {
            edescContextQuery = MatchQuery.of(m->m.field("eventsummary").query(contextSkill))._toQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Post which I have framed the boolean for the AND across field

```
SearchResponse<Event> responseSelected = esClient.search(s -> s.index("events").query(
                        q -> q.bool(b -> b.must(query1).must(query2))),
                        Event.class);
```

I am using a low level client for connecting to Elastic coded below

```
RestClient restClient = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200)).build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
    ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
    ElasticsearchClient esClient = new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
```

The loop overrides the query and I am unsure/ ignorant of how to frame the above explained criteria in the loop .Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: I got the answer from the link mentioned below, that bool (must) takes in a array/List  of Queries

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13352146/how-do-i-combine-multiple-queries-in-elasticsearch